# gstreamer: use d3d11h264dec after h264depay not negociated

Tags: windows, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I'm trying to setup a pipeline on gstreamer to decode a RTP stream with h264 encoding using GPU decode d3d11h264dec.

So far, I've made it work using avdec_h264 along with rtp pay/depay:

`gst-launch-1.0  dx9screencapsrc width=1920 height=1080 monitor=1 ! "video/x-raw, framerate=30/1" ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast threads=4 sliced-threads=true ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 max-threads=12 ! d3d11videosink`

I can also make it work using d3d11h264dec without RTP pay/depay:

`gst-launch-1.0  dx9screencapsrc width=1920 height=1080 monitor=1 ! "video/x-raw, framerate=30/1" ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=medium threads=12 ! d3d11h264dec ! d3d11videosink`

But not using both RTP pay/depay and d3d11h264dec:

`gst-launch-1.0  dx9screencapsrc width=1920 height=1080 monitor=1 ! "video/x-raw, framerate=30/1" ! videoconvert ! x264enc speed-preset=medium threads=12 ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! d3d11h264dec ! d3d11videosink`

The last one gives me an error `not negociated (-4)`.

I've tried adding a `h264parse` between depay and decoder as seen on some other issues, to no avail (same error).

I have to work on windows OS and the `d3d11videosink` is compulsory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from the default profile used by `x264enc` which is `profile=(string)high-4:4:4` , whereas d3d11h264dec can't handle it. One must force caps after x264enc. I also had to add h264parse after depay, I d'ont know why...The final pipe is:

`gst-launch-1.0  dx9screencapsrc width=1920 height=1080 monitor=1 ! "gst-launch-1.0  dx9screencapsrc width=1920 height=1080 monitor=1 ! "video/x-raw, framerate=30/1" ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! "video/x-h264, profile=(string)high" ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! d3d11h264dec ! d3d11videosink`